# Errors with 'echo [A-Z]*'

Tags: terminal, bash

Errors with 'echo [A-Z]*'

I am working on the root directory and intending to print those starting with upper letter.

```
$ echo [A-Z]*
Applications Library Network System Users Volumes bin cores dev etc home installer.failurerequests net private sbin tmp usr var vm
```

The result confuses me because 
`cores dev etc home installer.failurerequests net private sbin tmp usr var vm` doesn't match my pattern.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Are you using Apple's built in Terminal CLI? Is there anything in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`, etc?  This pattern matching `echo [A-Z]*` works absolutely as intended in both my home and root directories, as well as logged out in the basic `sh` shell. So, it's definitely not a problem with syntax but some issue with your configuration. Wish I could be of more assistance.

Comment: Bash has a 'nocaseglob' option which, if set, would cause this behaviour. You can check its value with 'shopt nocaseglob' and turn it off with 'shopt -u nocaseglob'.